# setParams not reflecting change in title of the UI

Tags: react-native

I have a functional component and I want the navigation title to be updated to a data that I get from a data storage. There are plenty of issues and blogs but I can't even get it to update to a literarl text.

DataScreen.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Button
} from 'react-native';

const DataScreen: () => React$Node = (props) => {

  const { navigation } = props;

  // didnt work
  const updateTitle = () =>{
      console.log('trying to update title')
        navigation.setParams({
        Title: 'New Title', // tired title as well
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateTitle();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
    <Button title="New Title" onPress={updateTitle} />
    </>
  );
};


DataScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: ' New Title',

  }

export default DataScreen;
```

if i do console.log(navigation) after calling updateTitle, I see "New Title". Hence, I think it is being set but not reflected in the UI.

my navigator object:

```
createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'Home',
        }),
      },
      Data: {
        screen: DataScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: 'Data'
        }),
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      headerMode: 'screen',
      mode: 'card'
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this

1. Update your createStackNavigator to reference the title from route.params.title (or Title, if you used capital T)

```js
createStackNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: navigation.state.params.title, // or Title if you use capital T
        }),
      },
      Data: {
        screen: DataScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
          title: navigation.state.params.title
        }),
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      headerMode: 'screen',
      mode: 'card'
    },
  );
```

or

2. Change setParams to setOptions (without changing anything in createStackNavigator)

```js
const DataScreen: () => React$Node = (props) => {

  const { navigation } = props;

  // didnt work
  const updateTitle = () =>{
      console.log('trying to update title')
        // navigation.setParams({
        // Title: 'New Title', // tired title as well
    // });
    navigation.setOptions({
        Title: 'New Title', // tired title as well
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateTitle();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
    <Button title="New Title" onPress={updateTitle} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Second option was better but setOptions is undefined (and console.log(navigation) don't show it either). I guess I will try the first option even

Comment: oh.. my bad. What react-navigation version do you use?

Comment: it looks like not react-navigation 5, so you may try the option 1. (I changed from route to navigation.state.params.title)

Comment: not exactly clear but after doing title: navigatin...params.title thing, I can update it as well on button click. I guess the state matters. Thanks.